# How to debug the JavaScript error "Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been coding a calculator but something doesn't work. I've been getting errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Calculator by Pavel (Dont block these popups, this website uses them)")
var a,b,result;
function setValues()
{
    a=number(document.getElementById("a").value);
    b=number(document.getElementById("b").value);
}
function sum()
{
    setValues();
    result= a+b;
    alert("The answer is"+result);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input id="a" type="text"/>
<input id="b" type="text"/>
<input type="button" onclick="sum()" value="sum"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course you're getting that. I don't see a `number()` declaration anywhere...

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I got my answer already, I had mistakes in caps and lowercase, so next time i shall watch out for these mistakes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake - `JavaScript` is case sensitive, so you must use `Number`

```
a=Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
```

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)**

Comment: Thanks.. I better keep an eye on my capslock -_-

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="a" type="text"/>
<input id="b" type="text"/>
<input id="1" type="button" onclick="sum()" value="sum"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sum()
{
    setValues();
    result= a+b;
    alert("The answer is"+result);
    // document.getElementById("ss").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    //  alert("hai");
}
    var a,b,result;
function setValues()
{

    a=Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
    b=Number(document.getElementById("b").value);

}
</script>
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/h4dqg3gr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a=parseInt(...); in place of a=Number(); to take numbers only. 
Give it a Try!

Comment: Hi, I have one more question.. what if I get this error??

Uncaught ReferenceError: parselnt is not defined